# CSS Button Border Rounded Shape inline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button which looks like following.

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8ubd.png)

So far I added this styling, but it does not equal to the button from the image, I am not able to make the box shadow rounded inside the div. And I am not sure if the box shadow is even the correct way of doing this.

```css
#custom-button {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 25;
  border: 0;
  height: 48;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 3px rgba(27, 215, 203);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="custom-button">Custom Button</button>
```

Comment: Both your `border-radius` and your `height` need a unit, like `px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is close to what you are looking for. I had to add an extra span inside the button to get all the elements though. You'll need to adjust some of the values to get it more to your liking.

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}
button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -4px;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: 50%;
  border: 8px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 35px 35px 0 0;
}
button span:before, button span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
  top: calc(50% + 4px);
  z-index: 1;
}
button span:after {
  left: -4px;
}
button span:before {
  right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span></span>
  test
</button>
```

Edit  - border bottom version

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}
button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -4px;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: 50%;
  border: 8px solid red;
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 35px 35px;
}
button span:before, button span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
  bottom: calc(50% + 4px);
  z-index: 1;
}
button span:after {
  left: -4px;
}
button span:before {
  right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span></span>
  test
</button>
```

Comment: This looks really good I am going to try it out, is this responsiveß

Comment: You'll need to take out the set width and use a combination of min-width and padding to get it to look right based on the text inside. You just need to mess with the values of those till it looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks :). How did you come up with this solution so quick, did you already done something similar to this? I need to improve my css I think :D

Comment: Honestly at first I was going to says it's not possible. But after a few years of being a frontend dev I've picked up some tricks, so I managed to come up with something quite quickly. Just takes time and practice.

Comment: How would I need to change is it, so that the border is at the bottom?

Comment: I've updated the comment with that version for you.